# My 6 years old boy behavior is terrible at school and home

Tags: discipline

My 6 year old son breaks everything can can put his hands on, talks back to me, and bothers his sister and brother all the time.

He can't stay focused in school and will be left behind this year, but I'm waiting for school evaluation so he could get help academically.

He lies about everything. It's been really hard and frustrating to say the least. Please help.

Comment: Hi and welcome. There is a lot of information missing that can be helpful for an answer. Have you searched the "discipline" tag? You may find similar questions. When did all this start? What kind of discipline have you tried, how has he responded, and why do you think it hasn't helped? Details are helpful to getting a relevant answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I can be of much help since I don't remember why I was such a headache when I was 8. But I have a few things I could say that might be worth considering.

Whenever I was reprimanded harshly, I reacted even worse, while whenever I was reprimanded calmly, sometimes with a tone of sad disappointment (usually from my grandfather), although sometimes still temporarily losing something precious as punishment, I reacted more positively, or at the very least, I began feeling that I was being unfair.

In fact, the few times I actually made my mother cry, it immediately weighed on my conscience and I regretted everything I had just said or done. In some cases I might not show it, but that was indeed how I felt, in other cases I would say I was sorry and in some of those cases an honest and calm conversation did follow.

I know reacting calmly or channeling frustration away from anger is easier said than done, especially after it has been building up for a long while, but I think it's something worthy of consideration.

Meanwhile, try to find out what exactly is the kid trying to accomplish, and whether he has any backwards reasoning causing his behavior. If he has some backwards ideas, then telling him those ideas are wrong may not help. He has to understand why they're wrong, and that's better achieved by showing it somehow, and with a positive attitude (this is also true for adults).

Answer (score 0):

As @agoodnurse says, there's not enough information. Starting with school, most six year old's have can't focus on things for long, unless he is seriously below national targets don't let it bother you and as to being held back a year, the positive side of it is he'll be well in advance of the kids who will join his class.

Lying, that's about discovering boundaries, the average adult lies many times a day, here you have to help him understand the cause and effect of lying - every kid does it and it's what they learn from other kids, adults and parents that helps them understand what lying is, how it works and the implications of it.

Talking back to you; Is it just you or to everyone and how is it done? Again this is an important thing for a child to learn, at his age he's being reactive to the environments he encounters, is it that he's copying another kid at school or elsewhere or is it that he's coping something he encounters in his home environment. Listen carefully to his language as he talks back, is it something you recognise. Does it sound like the way his brother and sister talk to him, does it sound like the way someone (an adult) talks to you. Generally at this age kids are starting to copy interactions that they see around them. It our job as a parent to role model how we would like them to interact. If you talk to a child with disrespect, don't be surprised if they talk back to you in the same way.

Bothering his brother and sister, that's what six year olds do, he wants to interact with his siblings, play with them learn from them have fun with them - it's normal and natural.

What you have basically described is normal feelings of most parents, it's basically called concern and it's not about discipline. Nearly all parents here who read what you have written will have felt those feeling frequently. As you've tagged it discipline, I feel that you looking for an answer about how to "punish out" these behaviours. The best form of discipline is to set a good role model and good standards, positive behaviours for your son to copy and from that he'll gain an understanding of right and wrong ways to behave.

Comment: Just fyi, the OP didn't tag the post with *discipline* (I did.) Her post was tagged "parent". Also, not everyone associates discipline with punishment. Many associate it with teaching and training, which are different.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to start by saying that I'm sorry you are having such a rough time with your son. It's my understanding, from the information that up provided, that he is the youngest?  Being the youngest can be hard.  It seems they either get left feeling out a lot or they are allowed to misbehave much longer than the rest because they're seen as "the baby" for so long.

From your limited description I am hearing a child that is feeling frustrated and angry but hasn't learned how to express it in a healthy way.  Also, children don't just start behaving this way over night...its a slow progression that develops over time.  Obviously he is getting reactions from his behavior, good or bad, and that is all children want. They don't care about the punishment, they're just looking for any reaction they can get.  What he is doing works and probably has been working for some time.

There are a few things I would suggest you start looking at regarding your son;

1) Diet.  What we take in has a huge affect on what we put out...and I mean that on every level. If your child (or even an adult for that matter) has a poor, unbalanced diet chaos will ensue. Cut out sugar, heavy carbs and pull back on the dairy. It has been proved these things cause mood swings, even in grown ups.

2) Sleep.  It would not shock me to find out your son is running bed time in the house, because who ever runs bed time, is the one in charge.  Does he have a routine? Is he getting all of the RM sleep he needs?  Is he sleeping on his own or co-sleeping (aka no one is sleeping)

3) Observe: So few parents take advantage of this very simple and useful technique. Instead what happens is the child acts and the parent instantly reacts which is generally followed by chaos and everyone being upset. This act/react method also leads to spanking, hitting, aggression, yelling and the list goes on. Next thing you know you have a frustrated parent and a poorly behaved child. This usually starts when they are 3 years old then escalates with time.

Take some time to set back and actually observe your child. I'll bet you can predict his behavior before it happens.  This is key. Stopping it before it starts.  If you know he is about to pick something up and break it...redirect him (and I don't mean yelling across the room for him to stop) I mean get up, walk over to him and ask him if he wants to play or go for a walk, maybe color or make cookies.  Something that brings you together and gives him what he is seeking; your time and attention.

Sometimes I hear stories about children breaking this or that, coloring on the wall, getting into something unsafe or not for them...then I ask, "where were you?" If that child had time to do what they are doing to misbehave, it means you weren't paying attention. He's 6...not 16.  He still needs to be supervised on a pretty consistent basis, and not by siblings. By adults.

Talking back; If he is talking back he is getting a reaction. What do you do when he talks back? Does he get his way? Do you yell at him, ignore him, talk back at him?

Lies; people lie out of fear.  And it doesn't have to be fear of punishment. It can just be fear of a face you make or a tone of voice you use.  Either way, he's getting a reaction of some sort.

As for him bothering his siblings...that too is him seeking out attention. He is getting a reaction.  It might be normal for him to want their attention but it is not okay for him to think it's okay just because he is 6.  He is old enough to learn when someone wants space.  I would suggest setting up an area in the house that is off limits to him during certain times. Your older children deserve a safe place too.  Incorporate a timer and tell your son that this space is off limits till the timer goes off.  Then take that time to give him that one on one he is seeking out.

Here is the reality, this isn't going to happen over night. He didn't just jump up one day and start behaving like this. His technique for getting attention has been created and locked in over years of trial and error.  This means it's going to take time to get it under control. Time and patience. Kind Communication and sticking to it for more than a few tries.

Is this the answer? I have no idea, but I hope it gives a little insight into another view that maybe hasn't been seen.  Because if you don't get a handle on it now...dealing with it in 10 years is going to be even worse. Best of luck!